# Connecting thousands of clients to a Jabber server through a single connection

Tags: java, scalability, xmpp

We are using Openfire (Jabber) to enable chat and presence capabilities to our MMORPG. In our server architecture clients only open a single connection with the game server, and upon login, the game server creates a new connection to Jabber for this new client.

The problem is, we don't want to open a new connection to Jabber for every client that logs in, we like it better if our game server acted as a connection manager and talked to the Jabber server through a single connection, yet being able to manage hundreds of thousands of 'logical' clients.

Is this possible?

Any links or info on this matter would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a local Jabber server separate from your game server, but on the same network and let it handle all the messy details?

If you have a massive game, you will most likely also need massive network.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a [connection manager for Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/connection_manager.jsp), open-sourced (though it does need an external library as well that is not OSS). It connects to the clients and from there talks to the main server as a [jabber component](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html). It sounds like you want to be able to do a similar thing with your own system.